# What is the default direction and value when a GPIO is exported?

Tags: android, linux, gpio, sysfs

What is the default direction and value when a GPIO is first-time exported?

Can I achieve a glitch-free operation using sysfs? I mean "export -> set direction -> set value" in atomic manner. For example, if I want a result of "Output-High", how can I avoid "Output-Low" intermediate GPIO state?

Comment: The default reset state is normally input so you aren't accidentally shorting something.  So set value first, then direction.

Comment: @starkYou said "normally", but what determines this outcome?

Comment: The specs for the chip.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the default direction and value when a GPIO is first-time
> exported?

In my experience, like [stark stated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71636952/what-is-the-default-direction-and-value-when-a-gpio-is-exported#comment126607126_71636952), default on export was always 'in'.
But I don't have the documentation for this.

> Can I achieve a glitch-free operation using sysfs?

Instead of writing 'out' + the value, you can directly write 'high' or 'low' as direction.
See line 70 ff. in https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/gpio/sysfs.txt

Note that the gpio sysfs interface is marked as deprecated.